# Extracting flexible general patterns

Tags: r

I'm looking for a simple and efficient way to extract general patterns of how elements repeat in a given vector (to later compare various vectors).
So this should allow for example to correct semantic problems, where some poeple would call an observation of a color "purple" while others would call it "violet" etc.
However, I need something very general and flexible, simple subsitution of terms is not realistic (since I don't know in advance all names that may come up).

Here a example of 3 vectors, the 1st and 2nd are the same, just the elements were called differently, however the 3rd is different

```
aa=letters[rep(c(3:1,4),each=2)]
ab=letters[rep(c(5,8:6),each=2)]
ac=letters[c(1:2,1:3,3:4,4)]
```

I tried

```
as.numeric(factor(aa,labels=unique(aa)))
as.numeric(factor(ab,labels=unique(ab)))
```

but as you can see, the result does not allow inidcating the same pattern for aa and ab (of always 2 repeats, until mooving to another item

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a run-length encoding function, in R, it is called `rle`; which gives you the lengths and values of each consecutive repeated value:

```r
rle(aa)$lengths
# [1] 2 2 2 2

rle(ab)$lengths
# [1] 2 2 2 2
```

Use `data.table::rleid` if you want to create an id along the values:

```r
data.table::rleid(aa)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4

data.table::rleid(ab)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aa=letters[rep(c(3:1,4),each=2)]
ab=letters[rep(c(5,8:6),each=2)]
ac=letters[c(1:2,1:3,3:4,4)]
```

Get universe of letters:

```
all_let<-c(aa,ab,ac)
```

Create vector of unique letters, and insert letters as name of each element:

```
 uni_let<-unique(all_let)
    
 names(uni_let)<-c(unique(all_let))
```

Create code id for each letter:

```
uni_code<-1:length(uni_let)
names(uni_code)<-names(uni_let)
```

Replace letter by code id, eg:

```
match(ac,names(uni_code))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are very intersting answers by @Maël and @BrunoPLC !
Unfortunately none of them solved exactely my original problem - maybe the question was not formulated clear enough.
Anyway, working with idea of @BrunoPLC I was able to find a solution.

Let's recapitulate the question : The aim is to identify generalized repeat-patterns in character vectors.
This way one can compare 2 vectors not using the same semantic 'vocabulary'.
Thus, in the example shown vectors *aa* and *ab* should be considered as 'the same' (after 2 repeats one moves to another new letter/word), while *ac* and *ad* are different (different order in ac, re-use of previous elements/letters in ad).

```
all(data.table::rleid(aa) ==data.table::rleid(ab))
# TRUE

## BUT
all(data.table::rleid(aa) ==data.table::rleid(ad))
# TRUE
```

Unfortunately, the approach using `data.table::rleid()` also considers *aa* and *ad* the same, although *ad* uses only 3 words.

Following the idea presented by  @BrunoPLC the basic pattern can be extracted combining `match()` and `unique()`:

```
basicPattern <- function(x) match(x, unique(x))
```

Thus, with the (extended) examples :

```
aa <- letters[rep(c(3:1,4), each=2)]
ab <- letters[rep(c(5,8:6), each=2)]        # 'same general' pattern to aa
ac <- letters[c(1:2,1:3,3:4,4)]             # NOT 'same general' pattern to any other
ad <- letters[rep(c(4,8,4,7),each=2)]       # NOT 'same general' pattern to any other

cbind(aa= basicPattern(aa),
  ab=basicPattern(ab),
  ac=basicPattern(ac),
  ad=basicPattern(ad) )

#      aa ab ac ad
# [1,]  1  1  1  1
# [2,]  1  1  2  1
# [3,]  2  2  1  2
# [4,]  2  2  2  2
# [5,]  3  3  3  1
# [6,]  3  3  3  1
# [7,]  4  4  4  3
# [8,]  4  4  4  3
```

Finally, one can compare two vectors using this function :

```
compPattern <- function(x, y) {if(length(x)==length(y) all(match(x, unique(x)) == match(y, unique(y))) else FALSE}
```

As expected, *aa* and *ab* are considered equivalent, while the others fail :

```
compPattern(aa, ab)
#  TRUE
compPattern(aa, ac)
#  FALSE
compPattern(aa, ad)
#  FALSE
```

Comment: Based on this post a more advanced function, replicateStructure() has been added to the package wrMisc (available on CRAN). This function allows to examine the global structure of all elements in a vector or to compare all columns of an data.frame for their role to explain replicates.